# Retrieving the last 24 hours of entries in Google App Engine Python datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

How could I retrieve the last 24 hours of entries from the current time of retrieval? Any help is much appreciated.

-Edit: They do have a DateTimeProperty of when they were added. I am specifically unsure of how to formulate a GQL query that would compare the current time and retrieve only the entries that are within 24 hours.

Comment: Do the entries have a timestamp?

Comment: Yes they do, a DateTimeProperty.

Comment: here's the answer I found for myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994187/how-to-query-all-entries-from-past-6-hours-datetime-in-gql/994215#994215

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this is to put timestamps on all your entities, and query for them individually (kind by kind) with a filter for only those created after the specified date.