# select records from last 48 hours with GQL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, google-cloud-datastore, gql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to query all entries from past 6 hours ( datetime) in GQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994187/how-to-query-all-entries-from-past-6-hours-datetime-in-gql)

Is there any way to select a number of records from GQL that were created within the last 48 hours?  This shows exactly what I want to do, but in SQL:  [How to select records from last 24 hours using SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888544/how-to-select-records-from-last-24-hours-using-sql) and variations of that don't seem to be working in GQL.

I am trying to use this query on a DateTime property and I have not set it to any particular format so it should be on the default.

Comment: Its not clear from your question about what value/type you are passing to your GQL query.  For all date and datetime queries the argument must be a datetime object and not a string date.  The system stores all datetime in UTC so you may need to take that into account down the track.

Comment: @jozzas thanks I didn't see that one.  that's right was I was looking for