# Return all entities (data) from the most recent put()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am using AppEngine with the Python runtime environment to host a dashboard for my team.  The data for the dashboard is stored in Memcache and/or Cloud Datastore.  New data is pulled into the application using the BigQuery API.

```
class ExampleForStackOverflow(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
        bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

        query = """SELECT field1, field2
                    FROM
                    [table_name];"""

        try:
            timeout = 10000
            num_retries = 5
            query_request = bigquery_service.jobs()
            query_data = {
                'query': (query),
                'timeoutMs': timeout,
            }

            query_response = query_request.query(
                projectId='project_name',
                body=query_data).execute(num_retries=num_retries)

            # Insert query response into datastore
            for row in query_response['rows']:
                parent_key = ndb.Key(MyModel, 'default')
                item = MyModel(parent=parent_key)
                item.field1 = row['f'][0]['v']
                item.field2 = row['f'][1]['v']

                item.put()

        except HttpError as err:
            print('Error: {}'.format(err.content))
            raise err
```

These queries will return an indeterminate number of records.  I want the dashboard to display the results of the queries regardless of the number of records so using order() by created and then using fetch() to pull a certain number of records won't help.

Is it possible to write a query to return everything from the last put() operation?

So far I have tried to return all records that have been written within a certain time window (e.g. [How to query all entries from past 6 hours ( datetime) in GQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994187/how-to-query-all-entries-from-past-6-hours-datetime-in-gql))

That isn't working for me in a reliable way because every so often the cron job that queries for the new data will fail so I'm left with a blank graph until the cron job runs the following day.

I need a resilient query that will always return data.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have an additional [`DateTimeProperty`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#Date_and_Time) type property in `MyModel`, let's call it `last_put`, which will have the `auto_now` option set to `True`. So the datetime of the most recent update of such entity would be captured in its `last_put` property.

In your `get()` method you'd start with an ancestor query on the `MyModel` entities, sorted by `last_put` and fetching only one item - it will be the most recently updated one.

The `last_put` property value of that `MyModel` entity will give the datetime of the last `put()` you're seeking. Which you can then use in your bigquery query, as mentioned in the post you referenced, to get the entities since that datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Dan's answer led me down the right path but I used a variation of what he suggested (mostly because I don't have a good understanding of ancestor queries).  I know this isn't the most efficient way to do this but it'll work for now.  Thanks, Dan!

My model:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
    field1 = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    field2 = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

My query:

```
query = MyModel.query().order(-MyModel.created)
query = query.fetch(1, projection=[MyModel.created])
for a in query:
    time_created = a.created
query = MyModel.query()
query = query.filter(MyModel.created == time_created)
```

Comment: Ancestor query is just a query in which you specify an ancestor key, which, in you case, is the common parent key:

Comment: `query = MyModel.query(ancestor=ndb.Key(MyModel, 'default')).order(-MyModel.created)`

Comment: Thanks, Dan!  I appreciate it.